# iOS - swipe up to zoom UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Is there a way to swipe up to zoom a scroll view? Specifically, I don't want to just zoom the content of the scroll view, instead, I want my entire scroll view to be zoomed so it's content can be zoomed with it

Comment: Do you mean that you want to scale up the whole scroll view frame? It would helpful if you can share some code and point out where you have got stuck.

Comment: My `UIScrollView` only takes half of the screen for now and it contains 5 subviews as its `contentView`. When I swipe it up, I want the entire `UIScrollView` to take full screen, of course this will make its `contentView` zoom as well.

Comment: @bohanl Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Setup a UIPanGestureRecognizer and then use its translationInView property to detect how far up a user has scrolled.  Based on the translationInView distance set the zoomScale on the UIScrollView (or if you actually want to scale the entire UIScrollView and not just its contents, set the transform to a scale transform on the UIScrollView's layer.)

Based on what you say above I would set the zoomScale on the UIScrollView to be greater than 1 so that the contents fill up more than half of the screen.

Comment: You can also set yourself as the delegate to the UIScrollView and look at the scroll offset to see if the user is scrolling up.  I am assuming that you want this behavior when they scroll up past the top.  The delegate still gets viewDidScroll delegate callbacks when the user scrolls past the top.  That would work better than gesture recognizer.